# Adding parent div's inside .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way I can include the wrapping div's `FilterListContainer`, `FilterListScroll` and `FilterList` in the `map` itself?

So if there is something to `map`, it will add the parent div's. If not it wont.

```
 <FilterListContainer>
      <FilterListScroll>
           <FilterList>
              {Object.keys(this.props.body_search_filter)
                .map((k) => (
                  <SidebarFilter
                    key={k}
                    type={k}
                    filter={this.props.body_search_filter[k]}
                    handleChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                  />
                ))
                .filter(
                  (i) =>
                    i.props.filter.list.length > 0 &&
                    ((!i.props.filter.optional && !i.props.filter.hidden) ||
                      (i.props.filter.list.length !== 1 &&
                        !i.props.filter.list[0].disabled))
           </FilterList>
      </FilterListScroll>
 </FilterListContainer>
```

Comment: Map it before render, check if there something in the array, render based on that?

Comment: Why filter after you map to JSX? That's a bit verbose and unwieldy.

Comment: @0stone0 So I'll have to map twice? Once to filter and store in an array, and second map to then render?

Comment: Anyways, you could use `{Object.keys(...).length && (JSX_goes_here)}`.

Comment: NO the render can be from the frist map ofc

Comment: @kellys Because I need the filter in order to hide certain options that are disabled.

Comment: I understand that, but why do it AFTER you create elements? You could do it before and that would save time from instantiating useless components.

Comment: @0stone0 Riiight... I think I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to use short-circuiting of logical operators here:

```
{Object.keys(this.props.body_search_filter).length && (
  <FilterListContainer>
      <FilterListScroll>
           <FilterList>
              {Object.keys(this.props.body_search_filter)
                .map((k) => (
                  <SidebarFilter
                    key={k}
                    type={k}
                    filter={this.props.body_search_filter[k]}
                    handleChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                  />
                ))
                .filter(
                  (i) =>
                    i.props.filter.list.length > 0 &&
                    ((!i.props.filter.optional && !i.props.filter.hidden) ||
                      (i.props.filter.list.length !== 1 &&
                        !i.props.filter.list[0].disabled))
           </FilterList>
      </FilterListScroll>
  </FilterListContainer>
)}
```

But you might want to filter the list, then check if the filtered list has any elements instead:

```
const filtered = Object.keys(this.props.body_search_filter).filter((k) => {
    const f = this.props.body_search_filter[k];

    return f.list.length > 0 && 
        ((!f.optional && !f.hidden) ||
            (f.list.length !== 1 && !f.list[0].disabled))
});

// ...

// then use 'filtered' instead

{filtered.length && (
  <FilterListContainer>
      <FilterListScroll>
           <FilterList>
              {filtered.map((k) => (
                  <SidebarFilter
                    key={k}
                    type={k}
                    filter={this.props.body_search_filter[k]}
                    handleChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                  />
              ))}
           </FilterList>
      </FilterListScroll>
  </FilterListContainer>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Moving [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72045597/adding-parent-divs-inside-map/72045703#comment127301201_72045597) to an answer to add a snippet</sub>

---

You could do the `map` before the `return`. Then you can 'check' if the `map` has some content, if so, use it, otherwise, don't render (or use fallback)

Please see comments in code

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    // Demo data
    const [data, setData] = useState([ 'foo', 'bar' ])

    // Filter + Mapping logic
    const mapped = data
      .filter(d => d !== 'foobar')
      .map(d => <li>{d.toUpperCase()}</li>);
    
    // Content based on map, use it, or render 'null'
    // The wrapped 'ul' is OP's FilterListContainer as an example
    const content = !mapped.length ? null :
      (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {mapped}
          </ul>
        </div>           
    );
    
    // Render
    return content;
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```